# get data from lumen error

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

I get an error "Undefined index: id_currency when calling data from lumen,please help me

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://139.59.113.86/zeeposapi/public/api/currency', [
'api_token' => ['']
]);

$decodedPosts = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
?>

<?php
foreach ($decodedPosts as $post)  { ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
        <?php echo $post['id_currency']; ?>
        </th>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: there is no `id_currency` in `$decodedPosts` to find out what you actually have `print_r($decodedPosts)`

Comment: Have you tried this `$decodedPosts['data']` rather than `$decodedPosts` in foreach?

Answer (score 0):

The error informs that the value of "id_currency" does not exist in the array.

**Output**

> {
>       "status": 1,
>       "data": [
>           {
>               "id_currency": 1
>           },
>           {
>               "id_currency": 2
>           }
>       ],
>       "totalCount": 2
>   }

You should use the following code

```
<?php foreach($decodedPosts["data"] as $post) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
        <?php echo $post['id_currency']; ?>
        </th>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks brooo, this is first time i used api and make me confused hehe